# como llamar a un metodo con before_filter despues de que se renderiza un parcial

Tags: web, ruby-on-rails, ruby, controller, callback

Ando trabajando en ruby on rails y pasa lo siguiente:

Al momento de renderizar una pagina.html.slim se me lanza un método desde el controller gracias a el siguiente comando:

```
before_filter :metodo_que_hace_algo, only: [:pagina]
```

Ese comando hace que cada que la pagina es renderizada se ejecuta el metodo.

Problema:

Hay varios parciales (fragmentos de HTML), lo que yo quiero saber es como hacer lo mismo pero cuando se renderiza un parcial algo como esto:

```
before_filter :otro_metodo_que_hace_algo, only: [:_parcial]
```

No se como lograrlo y soy nuevo en ruby on rails ... Ayuda por favor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A nivel de controlador no se sabe de la existencia de los partials que se van a renderizar a nivel de vista. Lo que podrías hacer es disponibilizar esos métodos para la vista con [`helper_method`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/AbstractController/Helpers/ClassMethods.html#method-i-helper_method), por lo tanto en tu controlador pones:

```
helper_method :otro_metodo_que_hace_algo
```

y luego en el partial, podrás llamar al método como tu estimes conveniente:

```
<% if otro_metodo_que_hace_algo %>
  ...
```

Si no es lo que esperas hacer, otra forma sería manejar las condiciones para renderizar uno u otro partial a nivel de controlador, disponibilizar el método como helper y usarlas tanto en tu `before_filter` como en la vista.

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo... eres un crack de la programaciòn.